# Want to use 'o' to enter a file in netrw

Tags: vim, neovim

Today I restarted my vimrc from scratch to try and trim it down.

I use vim-vinegar and use '-' to go up through the file tree a lot.

In my old setup, I have no idea why but 'o' opened the file, entirely in its own split, just like Enter does normally.

I really want 'o' back to open a file. I have no idea how I got it like that but I've been copying and pasting bits of my old vimrc with no luck. Maybe it was in some weird side effect of a plugin?! Who knows?

So the question: **how can I map o to Enter in netrw?!**

thanks

Comment: If you restore your old vimrc, does `o` work as you'd like it to? If so, can you go to a netrw buffer and check the output of `:verbose nmap o`? That would be a great hint to how it's made to work the way you like...

Comment: Great tip, thanks! I’ll try that.

Comment: Ok. Here is the situation. That output to 
n  o            @<CR>
        Last set from ~/.vim/after/ftplugin/netrw.vim line 1

so I looked in that file, and low and behold, the only thing in there was: nmap <buffer> o <CR>

So I thought I had solved it, but adding that to my init.vim (I'm using neovim) doesn't help!

Comment: Sorted, see below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If anyone gets here because they lost a weird setting for netwr and they couldn't reinstate it (probably because you switched to neovim) then:

you need to setup your ftplugin file.

First, add

`filetype plugin on`

to your init.vim. Then create a file, something like `.config/nvim/after/ftplugin/netrw.vim`.

Then put the thing you want, in there. In my case:

`nmap <buffer> o <CR>`

and hurrah! It worked!